# Функция для получения IP-адреса

Tags: delphi, ip-address

Address Port показывает, хочу узнать функцию опроса ip Address подскажите кто знает.

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,             
System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL,
  IdSSLOpenSSL;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Open;
  memo1.Text := 'Server started';
  { memo1.Text := '';}
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Close;
  memo1.Text := 'Server stopped'+' '+'Server Port: 
  ' + IntToStr(IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.BoundPort);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
{  memo1.Text := IntToStr(IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.BoundIP);
  memo1.Text := IntToStr(IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Id_IPv4);}
{  memo1.Text := IntToStr(IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1b.);}
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memo1.Text := IntToStr(IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.BoundPort);
end;

end.
```

[image: узнать функцию ip Address]

Comment: "функция опроса ip Address" что вам должна возвращать?

Comment: должна возвращать local  ip Address

Comment: Какой из? Вот (к примеру) у меня: 2 сетевых интерфейса с виртуалкой, 1 wi-fi и 1LAN. У всех есть локальные адреса. Зачем в конечном итоге он вам нужен? Возможно, для ваших целей вполне пойдет 127.0.0.1 или localhost

Comment: "функция опроса ip Address"  должна возвращать 1 wi-fi ip Address

Comment: спасибо, уже нашел ответ, функция работает: .BoundIP memo1.Lines.Add(IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.BoundIP);